# Images within text-based Tumblr post not appearing on Facebook/Twitter

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-opengraph, tumblr, meta-tags

I am trying to fix an issue where the correct images from text posts on Tumblr will appear on Twitter and Facebook when shared.

However at the moment whenever I share links it, it only shows a default website logo image. This is the current meta properties I have.

Facebook:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://40.media.tumblr.com/ead5cd62aae049daa2a0a3298140c6d3/tumblr_numuxlvfaX1r8no6so1_1280.png"/>
```

Twitter:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://static.tumblr.com/2shno8o/v2Wni0xt8/new_ah_logo_white_with_black_bg.png" />
```

I'm guessing I need to add a default id/class within the image element in my text post but I am not sure how to connect it to the meta tags.

```
<img src="https://41.media.tumblr.com/5eaa1c9e156caf61c139778b4f81e86b/tumblr_inline_nrftnqzKjB1t3m09q_540.jpg" width="250px">
```

I am wanting the image that shows from each individual text-based post to show when links are shared on Facebook and Twitter.

Any help?